# PyhonによるサーバーAPIの利用

Tags: python, api, conoha

サーバーを提供しているconohaでAPIを利用しようと試みておりますが躓いております。
やりたいことはAPIを利用したサーバーの追加です。
https://www.conoha.jp/docs/compute-create_vm.html

既にUserトークンやimage vmプランのuuidは別のAPIを用いて取得し終えています。
ページにはrequest parametersとrequest jsonがあります。
headerとjsonデータを同時にpostしたいのですが下のようなコードであっていますでしょうか？
下のようなエラーが表示されます。postの所が大丈夫か不安です。

> `{'bad request':{'message':'Missing flavorRef attribute','code':400}}`

```
import requests
import json

json_data2={
    "server": {
        "imageRef": aaa,
        "flavorRef": bbb,
        "adminPass":"ccc"
    }
}
parm={"X-Auth-Token":ddd}
    url4="https://compute.tyo1.conoha.io/v2/0ff2f439801145a6a44bfd9488fd360e/servers"
    ress4= requests.post(url=url4,json=json_data2,data=json.dumps(parm))
    print("\n")
    print (ress4.status_code)
    print(ress4.json())
    print(ress4)
    print()
```

Comment: `X-Auth-Token`はヘッダーとして指定するべきではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

以下のページに requests の使い方が書いてあります。
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

ヘッダは `headers=` に指定するようですので、

```
ress4= requests.post(url=url4,json=json_data2,headers=parm)
```

でいかがでしょうか。

---

あと、どうも勘違いされているような気がするのですが、
ConoHa のそのページについては、
Request Parameters がリクエストの仕様で、Request Json は POST で送信する JSON データの例で、Request Parameters の表だけではよく解らない点は Request Json に書いてある例で読み取ってください、ということだと思います。